# Angular show checkbox checked filter

Tags: angularjs

I have a group object that contains a list of video
And when you edit the object, i give the HTML a list of all videos, where you can search in.

But if you don't search I want it to show only the videos that are checked.

here is the HTML used

```
<div class="input-field">
    <input type="text" id="filter" ng-model="query" ng-change="hasVideos()" />
    <label for="filter"><i class="mdi-action-search"></i></label>
</div>

<ul class="collection">
    <li class="collection-item" ng-repeat="video in filterdVideo = (videos | filter:query) ">
        <p>
            <input type="checkbox" id="video_{{video.Id}}" checklist-model="group.Keywords" checklist-value="video.Id">
            <label for="video_{{video.Id}}">
                {{video.Title}}
            </label>
        </p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

So how can I make it that it only shows the video list where the checkbox is checked? and when the query isn't empty to ignore that and show all.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to improve my answer later.

But for a quick guess you might be able to use ng-if and let the controller handle if something should be listet.

```
<li ng-if="functionthatreturnstrueorfalsebasedonyourneeds" class="collection-item" ng-repeat="video in filterdVideo = (videos | filter:query) ">
```

Checkbox example can be found in the docs:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by doing a filter:

```
filter('filterStack', function () {
    return function (inputs, filterValues, showAll) {
        var output = [];
        if (showAll) return inputs;

        angular.forEach(inputs, function (input) {
            angular.forEach(filterValues, function (filterVal) {
                if (filterVal.Id == input.Id) {
                    output.push(input);
                }
            });
        });
        return output;
    };
})
```

but having an other issue now, when loading it in with data: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29749006/angular-checklist-model-not-checking